# can't get javascript to work on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby

I am trying to run the areyousure dirty form checker in a rails app. It needs to load after document ready.

I tested things with the following code on one of my /new pages.

```
<script>

alert("well we got here at least");
$('form').areYouSure();
var do_on_load = function() {


    alert("test test test!");
}
$(document).ready(do_on_load)
$(window).bind('page:change', do_on_load)

</script
```

The first alert comes up "well we got here at least" but the second alert does not show.

I am assuming that either the code is bad or the page isn't getting to the document.ready status.

Is there a reason I don't seem to be getting to the var do_on_load function?

Comment: Are you making sure to load jQuery?

Comment: you are initializing plugin outside of document.ready

Comment: @charlietfl both thumbs up.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your syntax error-

$(document).ready(do_on_load);  // you have passed reference so ,it will return function definition

correct syntax

$(document).ready(do_on_load()); //need to call function inside it . it will return second alert("test test test!");

Comment: The syntax error fixed the major problem. It seems that I had to also disable turboLinks for that page but that is a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

It already works, you have some other error 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lwnxm0sa/

```
alert("well we got here at least");
$('form').areYouSure();
var do_on_load = function() {


alert("test test test!");
}
$(document).ready(do_on_load)
$(window).bind('page:change', do_on_load)
```